# Why is $location.absUrl(), $location.$$url, $location.$$path blank in href?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook-sharer, location-services

Here is the code in concern:

```
<div ng-app="">
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{$location.absUrl()}}
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{$location.$$url}}
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{$location.$$path}}
</div>
```

We need the value of the `u` parameter to be current page.
Where are we wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that in HTML, alternatively you can get the current location like this,

Assign the curren location to a scope variable,

```
  $scope.a = window.location.href;
```

Then in HTML,

```
   <br>Link = <a ng-href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{a }}" target="_blank">facebook</a>
```

**DEMO**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.a = window.location.href;
    }]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
     <input type="text" ng-model="a">
    <br>a={{a}}
    <br>
    <br>Link = <a ng-href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{a}}" target="_blank">facebook</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The property which are present of `$scope` variable those are only available to use on HTML as binding. So `$location` service you have to expose on `$scope`

```
//inject $location to controller before use it.
$scope.$location = $location;
```